# java: primitive arrays -- are they initialized?

Tags: java, arrays

If I use a statement in my code like

```
int[] a = new int[42];
```

Will it initialize the array to anything in particular? (e.g. 0) I seem to remember this is documented somewhere but I am not sure what to search for.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

At [15.10 Array Creation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) the JLS says

> [...] a single-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value

and at [4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) it says:

> For type `int`, the default value is zero, that is, `0`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994421/are-multi-dimensional-arrays-zero-inited

Comment: @ripper234: It seems from the link that your first comment is incorrect. Would you consider removing it?

Comment: @ripper234 I mean that your question which you linked to shows that your first comment `"Note that I just discovered this is NOT TRUE for multi-dimensional arrays" - ripper234` is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

When created, arrays are automatically initialized with the default value of their type - in your case that would be `0`. The default is `false` for `boolean` and `null` for all reference types.

Answer (score 4):

The array would be initialized with 42 0s

For other data types it would be initialized with the default value ie.

```
new boolean[42]; // would have 42 falses
new double[42]; // would have 42 0.0 ( or 0.0D )
new float[42]; // 42  0.0fs
new long[42]; // 42  0Ls
```

And so on.

For objects in general it would be null:

```
String [] sa = new String[42]; // 42 nulls 

Date [] da = new Date[42]; // 42 nulls
```

Answer (score 0):

All elements in the array are initialized to zero. I haven't been able to find evidence of that in the Java documentation but I just ran this to confirm:

```
int[] arrayTest = new int[10];
System.out.println(arrayTest[5]) // prints zero
```

Comment: Testing a specific implementation is not a good way to verify that every implementation behaves this way. It's better to check the documentation/specification, because if it isn't specified/documented then other implementations could handle it differently. That's more of problem in other languages, because Java has very few places with undefined/implementation-specific behaviour, but it's still true.

Comment: Further more - if it's ain't in the spec - behavior can be changed on a newer version of the same implementation.

Comment: Also, your making assumptions that another method behaves in a specific way without evidence (println .. the method could translate null to 0, for example)

Comment: On the other hand, just because something is in the spec doesn't mean it actually works in any particular implementation. I don't rely on HTML specs very far, for example, as browser implementation of many features is spotty.

Comment: Unless Java plans to allow inline assembly instructions, it is always going to zero-out the array for you.  To do otherwise would be a performance killer.