# I have a function in java which may have bug and I can not find it

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code which suppose to do the following task:
For example , given M=3, and array built like this:

```
A[0]=1
A[1]=1
A[2]=3
A[3]=3
A[4]=5
A[5]=1
A[6]=3
```

the function may return 1 or 3

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    int solution(int M, int[] A) {
        int N = A.length;
        int[] count = new int[M + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
            count[i] = 0;
        int maxOccurence = 1;
            int index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                if (count[A[i]] > 0) {
                    int tmp = count[A[i]];
                    if (tmp > maxOccurence) {
                        maxOccurence = tmp;
                        index = i;
                    }
                    count[A[i]] = tmp + 1;
                } else {
                    count[A[i]] = 1;
                }
            }
            return A[index];
        }
    }
```

what could be the problem because it is not always working and I can see there is a bug in my program.

Comment: *"the function may return 1 or 3"* - why? According to what logic is that supposed to happen? Given only that requirement `return 3;` would be a valid implementation.

Comment: What is the input M, and what is the purpose of the function? In other words, what is your task trying to accomplish? Since you say, that your example could return 1 or 3, is it trying to calculate the mode?

Comment: array element having more than M occurrences maybe

Comment: Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944535/java-primitive-arrays-are-they-initialized).

Comment: I have the M input which indict how many occurneces of the number in the array A occurs

Answer (score 1):

1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 this is a case where your code may fail. Check and update the max occurance variable outside the loop too. Above case give enough justice to my point, i hope.

Comment: yeah could be the problem

Comment: @ErezN also M should be the max(array_elements)+1.