# Java Try Catch if 4 numbers are entered, 3 int inputs expected via array & while loop iterator

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, try-catch

I'm troubleshooting my Java program to use a while loop and a try-catch statement to throw an exception if 4 integer inputs are entered by a user when only three are expected. I use an array combined with a while loop and the hasNextInt method but I can't get it to run. Any insight would be great.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 3;

    int[] numbers = new int[count];
    System.out.println("Enter 3 integers");
    Scanner numScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
    while (numbers[] > count) {
        if (numScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            numbers[] = numScanner.hasNextInt();
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("You didn't provide enough numbers");
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your numbers[] variable needs a index inside the square brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to note, you need to provide a index when you accessing a element in the array also in java primitive arrays are initialized to zero by default[1] thus your condition on while statement fails. Also you need to close your scanners.

Following code is slightly edited. I hope it meets your expected result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 3;
        int[] numbers = new int[count];
        System.out.println("Enter 3 integers");
        Scanner numScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
        int currentIndex = 0;
        while (currentIndex < count) {
            if (numScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                numbers[currentIndex] = numScanner.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("You didn't provide enough numbers");
                break;
            }
            currentIndex++;
        }
        numScanner.close();
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

1. [java: primitive arrays -- are they initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944535/java-primitive-arrays-are-they-initialized)